# Removing RPM Packages

Tags: linux, package, rpm

Hello experts and thank you for taking your time to answer the question:

Can I remove the .rpm files after having installed the program?

EXAMPLE:

I have installed the rar.rpm file and now I have the rar.rpm in a directory where I downloaded the file and want to know if I could remove that file without disrupting the rar program's function in centos.

Regards
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Though you may want to keep it in case you need to install it again.

Also, in general, you shouldn't be (and shouldn't need to) use randomly downloaded `.rpm` files.

You should usually be using `yum` or similar tool to install a package from the configured repositories on the system.